# mysql input data with foreign key constrain

Tags: php, mysql

I have two simple table on Mysql Db with a foreign key constrain, let's say:

User (Userid,Name)
BorrowedBook (BookTitle, Userid)

I need to populate these table through a form, thus using Php.
What's the best practice to input consistent data on User and BorrowedBook?

I tried in several ways, including two separate INSERT INTO but I do have error message on Foreign Key constrain.

Comment: Insert the primary key (PK) first, then you are able to insert the another table (foreign key FK). I think your answer is here -> http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key

Comment: Assuming that the FK constraint refers from `BorrowedBook` to `User`, insert the data into the `User` table first, then `BorrowedBook`.

Comment: Example is a bit different, but at end it helped me a lot and now works. I'm surprised that there isn't a common practice for it, I assume largest share of php/mysql programmer deal with populating tables with relation.